# how to Pass one Variable value from parent window to new Child window in html using javascript

Tags: query-string, session-variables

I think the one way is query string. But i don't know whether it works on local machine or we need server-side or local-server. And How we implement in the page1(parent window) and page2 (popup).

Can any body here help me to do this. please write the steps to do this. Correct Answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Passing values through query strings will work without server-side support.

In page1: `window.open('url?param1=value1');`

In page2: (after page load):

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/384155)

```
function getParameterByName(name) 
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
console.log(getParameterByName(param1));
```